# TextFormField: Show suffixIcon only if text field is wide enough

Tags: flutter

I have a `TextFormField` component with a suffixIcon. But some of my input fields are quite some, as they only accept 2 or 3 characters. I want to hide the suffixIcon automatically if the text field is too small. Is this possible?

```
TextFormField(
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    suffixIcon: IconButton(
      icon: Icon(
        Icons.clear,
        color: ThemeColors.iconColor,
      ),
      onPressed: () {
        _controller.clear();
      },
    )
  ),
  controller: _controller 
)
```

**Edit:**

The width of the text field is not fixed - I don't know its width. Usually, the text field is integrated into a flexible layout, e.g. in Rows.

So, in fact, I need to know the width of a flexible text field.

Comment: Did you checkout LayoutBuilder? It gives you the constraints and you can find width from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the constraints provided by the LayoutBuilder and update the UI accordingly. You can use constraints.maxWidth and compare it with your value

Your code will be updated as follows

```
LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, constraints) {
  print(constraints.maxWidth);

  return TextFormField(
    decoration: InputDecoration(
      suffixIcon: constraints.maxWidth > YOUR_VALUE ? IconButton(
        icon: Icon(
          Icons.clear,
          color: ThemeColors.iconColor,
        ),
        onPressed: () {
          _controller.clear();
        },
      ) : null,
    )
  );
});
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks! That made it!

Comment: So it's possible to use the ternary operator without the second (falsy) condition?

Comment: @funder7 I don't think that would be possible.

Answer (score 0):

Yes just wrap you widget which you want to hide with Visibility and add condition to check whether the input field length is greater or smaller

Comment: This is exactly my problem. How do I know my width?